# Column names into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, environment-variables, names

How can I create a data frame which contains the column names of **all Environment objects (df)**

Ex. Having this 3 df as all the objects in the global environment.

```
chocolate <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
banana <- data.frame(a = 2, d = 4, c = 3)
pear <- data.frame(d = 1, e = 4)
```

Desired output

```
output <- data.frame(id = c("chocolate","banana", "pear"), 
                 v2 = c("a", "a", NA), 
                 v3 = c("b", NA, NA), 
                 v4 = c("c", "c", NA), 
                 v5 = c(NA, "d", "d"), 
                 v6 = c(NA, NA, "e"))
output
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? The structure is very strange and you can probably accomplish what you want in a simpler manner.

Comment: You can just use `dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)` and you should get a usable output.

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(ls()) ` if there are more dataframes than the OP cares to type out, and there are no other objects in the way.

Comment: @Imo I have to import thousands of tables into R and find similar columns between them. Do you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:3))
setnames(rbindlist(lapply(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)), function(x) {
         x[] <- names(x)
           x}), fill = TRUE, idcol = 'id'), 2:6,  paste0("V", 1:5))[] 
#   id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1:  1  a  b  c NA NA
#2:  2  a NA  c  d NA
#3:  3 NA NA NA  d  e
```

Comment: your solution is not working as a general solution. I want the code works for **all environmental variables**. I update the post with diferent names.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF You can put whatever you want inside `mget`. Use `lst <- mget(ls())` if you want every object in the environment. Use `lst <- mget(ls())[sapply(mget(ls()), is.data.frame)]` for every data frame in the environment. Adapt as desired. Use the `pattern` argument of `ls()` if you only want names with specific patterns. Use `all.names = T` if you want hidden objects. See `?ls` for details.

Comment: @Gregor I solve that problem but when I apply the setnames function I getting this error: "Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected"